# Where can I find a list of Marie Curie fellowship-funded projects?

Tags: funding, marie-curie

If such a list does exist, it should since the funding comes from public money. I would like to see as much information as possible. I am interested in the Individual Fellowship but I guess any Marie Curie as this might be useful for people applying for other fellowship types.

Comment: I do not know particularly about Marie-Curie (did you check the web-site?) but, unfortunately, there are fellowships in public institutions funded from public money that they provide no info whatsoever (no info about projects, selection criteria, evaluation, statistics, etc)

Comment: It's more a question about searching on the Web rather than about academia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find EU funded projects in [CORDIS](http://cordis.europa.eu/projects/home_en.html). For example, a list of all Marie Curie individual fellowships funded under the Horizon 2020 programme can be found [here](http://cordis.europa.eu/projects/result_en?q=(contenttype%3D'project'%20OR%20/result/relations/categories/resultCategory/code%3D'brief','report')%20AND%20programme/code%3D'H2020-EU.1.3.2.*').